# How to catch value when back to previous screen?

Tags: dart, flutter

this is my second class

```
class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
   _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}

class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Return Container(
      RaisedButton(
       onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop('lorem ipsum),
       child: Text('Back and get data')
      )
    );
  }
}
```

this is my first class

```
class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}

class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     Return Container(
       // show data here
     );
  }
}
```

How to get string of `lorem ipsum` and display it in first class, where I should put the code to get that string?

Comment: You should put the code when you are navigating to the second class, like a button `onPressed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can see in the screenshot, whatever item is clicked in 2nd screen, it is sent back to page 1 and Button shows the same item.

---

Here is the full code for a basic implementation.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Page1()));
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  String _response = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 1")),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Go to Page 2"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2())).then((value) {
              setState(() {
                _response = value; // you receive here
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Page 2")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (c, i) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("Item ${i}"),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, "Item ${i}"); // what you pass here
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondClass())).then((value) {
  // value is lorem ipsum
});
```

You should use this in your `FirstClass` when you are navigating to the `SecondClass`.

---

Full solution:

```
class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
  String _string = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Go"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondClass())).then(
          (value) {
            setState(() {
              _string = value; // lorem ipsum
            });
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I go to my second class use `onPressed: (){ return SecondClass(); }` in second class I have a list, I want when I press that list, the app back to previous screen and display data that I press.

Comment: In second class, when you click on the list probably you would be using `ListTile`, in its `onTap()` method, use Navigator.pop(context, "your_value"). Simple!

Comment: ok, I did what you wrote. when I press ListTile, the app back to previous screen (first class), then how I can get "your_value" in my first class when the app back to previous screen?

Comment: Please post your complete code. You were not able to do it correctly.